# App Store download paused due to internet disconnection

Tags: mac, macos, xcode, mac-appstore

I tried to download Xcode from the Mac app store and the internet connection stopped at some point. It has downloaded more that 3 GB out of 4.53 GB. Now that I got my internet connection back, but the download stopped entirely.

[image]

I tried to open it, but it cannot be opened:

[image]

Should I go back to App Store and continue the download. But I am afraid that it will [re-download the app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136540/). What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll automatically resume the progress of the download.